# Controller to be able to search for first and last name

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder, entitymanager

I am trying to make this controller more dynamic by allowing the controller to be able to make a search with First and Last name.  Right now, the controller only search by first name and last name and email address.  Id like to be able to input in the filter "$filter= Chris smith" and query for "Chris smith" results.

Below is my controller.

public function getEventSessionAttendeeAction(request $request, $eventSessionId)
    {

```
    $filterName = 'filter';

    $searchFields = [
        'o.email',
        'a.email',
        'a.firstName',
        'a.lastName',
        'a.barcode1',
        'a.barcode2',
        'a.id',
        'o.id',
        $lname = 'a.lastName',
        $fname = 'a.firstName'
    ];

    $filter = $request->get('filter');
    $match_level = 0;

   if ( filter_var($filter, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $searchFields = [
        'a.email'
    ];
    $match_level = 1;

    }elseif(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\-]*$/', $filter)){
      $searchFields = [
         'a.lastName',
         'a.firstName'
     ];
      $match_level = 2;
   }else{
       $lname = 'a.lastName';
       $fname = 'a.firstName';
   }



    try {
      /** @var ApiEntity\EventSession $eventSession */
//          $eventSession = $this->get('doctrine')->getRepository('KCMApiBundle:EventSession')->findOneById($eventSessionId);
//          $eventAttendees = $this->getEventSessionAttendeesCheckedIn($eventSession);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
           $qb ->select('a.firstName, a.lastName, a.relationship, a.dateOfBirth, a.barcode1, a.phoneNumber, ea.address1, ea.address2, ea.city, ea.state, ea.country, ea.postal, s.name, s.keynoteSpeaker, ci.created, \'checkin\' AS event')
            ->from('KCMApiBundle:EventSessionCheckin', 'ci')
            ->innerJoin('ci.eventSession', 's')
            ->innerJoin('ci.eventAttendee', 'a')
            ->leftJoin('a.eventAttendeeAddresses', 'ea')
            ->where($qb->expr()->andX(
               $qb->expr()->eq('ci.eventSession', $qb->expr()->literal($eventSessionId))
           ));
//                ->where('ci.eventSession = :sessions')
//                ->groupBy('a.id', 's.id')
//                ->setParameter('sessions', $eventSessionId)



        $expr = $qb->expr()->orX();

        foreach ($searchFields as $field){
            if ($match_level === 1){
                $literalFilter = $filter;
                $expr->add($qb->expr()->like($field, $qb->expr()->literal($literalFilter)));
            }elseif ($match_level === 2){
                $literalFilter = $filter;
                $expr->add($qb->expr()->eq($field, $qb->expr()->literal($literalFilter)));
            }else{
                $literalFilter = $filter;
                $expr->add($qb->expr()->concat($lname, $qb->expr()->concat($qb->expr()->literal($literalFilter), $fname)));
            }
        }

        $qb->andWhere($expr);

        $results = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

        if ($results) {

            return $this->getApi()->serialize($results);

        }

        return new Response(null, Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->get('logger')->error($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read the part on [Criteria](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections) in the Doctrine docs? They give a few examples. Also, they're a database engine _independent_ way of writing queries in a human readable format. As in: you could use `Criteria` created "queries" and apply them on all supported database types, e.g MySQL, PostgreSQL, MongoDB, etc. Please provide more information on what you've looked up and tried.

Comment: @rkeet What i am trying to do is to do a query builder that fetches with a get request the URL for "first name" and "last name".   Then, pass that on as a query to search results in a search critiera such as;

Chris smith (to an end point)

get returns results for just chris smith.   

right now, my search just searches through a first or last name but i need to ability to be able to have an user input "Chris Smith" and queries.  

I updated my origianal msg to reflec this.  If you can help me, that be great.

Comment: Sure, could you first have a look at [an answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55469458/1155833) from a few months ago? If you can figure it out from there, that'd be great. If not, I'll give writing an answer a shot ;)

Comment: (Don't forget to combine with [Hugo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56565761/1155833) - that's also a good step towards what you need to know about the QB - else there's the [QB code](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.php) and [Criteria code](https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/Criteria.php)) itself of course. Hint: check namespaces, DBAL QueryBuilder **is not the same as** ORM QueryBuilder)

Comment: @rkeet I gave a whirl, i seem to be stuck, i got everything working except the first and last name part :(

Answer (score 0):

`orX()` allow you to make conditional statements with Doctrine.

e.g. if you want to get the blue or the red cars :

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('cars');

$firstCondition = $qb->expr()->eq('cars.color', 'blue');
$secondCondition = $qb->expr()->eq('cars.color', 'red'); 

$qb->where($qb->expr()->orX($firstCondition, $secondCondition));
$qb->setParameter('blue', 'blue');
$qb->setParameter('red', 'red');

$result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

You can get the same result doing :

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('cars');

$qb
    ->where('cars.color = :blue')
    ->orWhere('cars.color = :red')
    ->setParamters([
        'blue' => 'blue',
        'red' => 'red',
    ])
;

$result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: what about expr()    ?

is that just an instantiation for orX() ?

Comment: `expr()` is giving you access to an instance of `Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr`, which is an helper for building expressions, as it is explained in [the documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class).